# Xamarin.Forms Binding inside Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a `ObservableCollection<IDictionary<string, object>>` as `ItemSource` for a `ListView`. Inside I use a custom `ViewCell` that has, let's say, an `Entry` inside.

Now of course the `BindingContext` for it is an `ExpandoObject` and I can bind the value stored for the key `Name` to the `Entry.Text` in XAML by writing:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding [Name]}" />
```

Works fine so far, but what I want to do is to get the key (`Name` in this case) from a property inside the custom `ViewCell` (This may sound weird but in fact this is a sub-view of the actual custom `ViewCell` and the `ViewCell`itself actually represents a row in a table).

So what I tried to do is:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding [{Binding Key, Source={x:Reference cell}}]}" />
```

To be sure it's not a problem about the "inner" Binding, i also tried:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Key, Source={x:Reference cell}}" />
```

This (as expected) lets `Entry.Text` be `Name`.

Now obviously what I want to achive is to use a Binding inside the Binding path. As the code above doesn't work (`Entry.Text` is `null`), I wonder if this is possible and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding on binding won't work.
Do your binding on the key with a converter.